# Defining a metric in the tangent spaces $ T_xM $

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, differential-topology, grassmannian

I'm working with a metric $D$ over the manifold of grassman $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and have difficulties to extend $D$.
Let me explain:

If $M$ is a submanifold of dimension $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ then $T_xM\in G_n(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ for all $x\in M$. therefore I can check the closeness of two elements through $D$.

I wonder if I could do the same in the general case of a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$?

That is, if $M$ is manifold of dimension $n$ for Whitney embedding theorem
exists $f:M\rightarrow f(M)\subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ diffeomorphism. Then $d_xf:T_xM\rightarrow T_{f(x)}f(M)$ and I am tempted to define
$$D(T_xM,T_yM):=D(d_xf(T_xM),d_yf(T_yM))$$

but this causes problems . I appreciate it if I could suggest a way to measure these tangent spaces.

**Edit**:  I wonder if the fibers of a vector bundle $TM$ are continuous.

thanks for the help

Comment: I'm confused what you are trying to do. Are you trying to define a metric on $ TM $? There are in general, many metrics on a manifold. Is there some compatibility condition you need?

Comment: Do not think it's possible for defining a metric in $ TM $ elements are pairs $(x,v)$.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In general your construction is poorly behaved - for any two points (and more generally for any closed ball) you can find an embedding where the tangent spaces agree (up to shift), and so give the same element of the grassmanian.

Comment: @Tirifilo:Why not? TM is a manifold, and every (paracompact) manifold can be given a metric.

Comment: @user226970:I mean a metric on $ TM $ bundle would measure the distance between the elements of $ TM $, that is, two points of the form $( x, v ) $ and not set $T_xM$ , $T_yM$.

Comment: @Max: I think the tangent spaces do not address the same element in the grasmanian because the isomorphism is at each point. I try to do ? I wonder if the fibers of a vector bundle are continuous.

Comment: @Tirifilo Ah, I see. I did not think this through, but once you choose a metric on $ TM $ you can use the Hausdorff distance on subsets?